# How to make a splash screen and run listview processes at background?

Tags: android, listview

I have an app which loads the data from sqlite db, does some calculations with it and presents it using listview with adapter. So this part is ready and is working. In case when the data is big enough the calculation time may get long. This is important because my activity won't show until all the elements of list are not ready. For this reason I would like to show a splash screen at the start and show it until all the data in MainActivity is not ready. If there is some tutorial on it or any advice I would really apperiate that.

However, I need to add another info that this MainActivity that is responsible for showing the listView is the central unit in whole app. User will often reopen to this page later after app is launched. So the method that updates or creates the new listview items from sqlite db must be available outside of the splash screen activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class SplahActivity extends Activity {

        public static final int Tick = 1000;
        public static final int Complete = 5000;
        ArrayList<String> data;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            data = new ArrayList<>();
            AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
            String sleepTime = time.getText().toString();
            runner.execute(sleepTime);

        }

        private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            private String resp;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
                // example showing ProgessDialog
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // data and save it in array
               // data = Reveice data from db
                return resp;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // execution of result of Long time consuming operation

                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityName.this,SecondScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }
```