# Setting values for UI Thread after data is collected?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

this is a theoretical question!

I am currently developing an android application.There I would like to collect data and then edit the UI. But when I am waiting for finishing data collection I am obviously blocking the UI Thread().

So the question is: How can I make app to wait for the data collection without blocking the UI Thread? Is a loading screen with the appsymbol and a progress bar an option?

Edit: To make it clear: My data collect is seperated in several small data fetches!

Edit 2: I am collecting the data form the internet!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it about how to do long running work on a separate thread? Or what the UI should look like while the separate thread is busy?

Comment: You can do it using async task, where you will be able to handle ui thread as well as collect data simultaneously

Comment: from where do you collect data ? Is this a web service ?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588727/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-and-run-listview-processes-at-background/37589675#37589675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an AsyncTask, then simply display ProgressDialog on preExecute of AsyncTask. Do the time consuming and application freezing things like retrieving data from Link on doInBackground. Do the post Link retrieved works in the onPostExecute of asyncTask and dismiss the `ProgressDialog. AsyncTask runs on a diffrent thread from the main activity and hence the application doesn't freeze.

ASYNC TASK

```
class ClassName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading ...",
                false, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Your Code
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if (progress != null) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for simple data fetch. If its more complicated use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)